# Entrybox input copied into another entrybox and still be able to edit input independently

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im trying to gather the input from one entrybox and then putting it into another entrybox. I can do this using a Stringvar but i want to 
be able to edit the second entry without changing the other.

```
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()

var_ip = StringVar()
var_mask = StringVar()
var_gateway = StringVar()


def user_input_ip():
    input_ip = entry_ip.get()
    display_ip = input_ip
    var_ip.set(display_ip)


entry_ip = Entry(my_window, font="Helvetica 15", textvariable=var_ip)
entry_ip.place(x=35, y=100, width=158, height=30)
entry_ip.bind("<Tab>", focus_next_widget)
entry_ip.bind("<Return>", enter_key)


def user_input_mask():
    input_mask = entry_mask.get()
    display_mask = input_mask
    var_mask.set(display_mask)


entry_mask = Entry(my_window, font="Helvetica 15", textvariable=var_mask)
entry_mask.place(x=35, y=165, width=158, height=30)
entry_mask.bind("<Tab>", focus_next_widget)
entry_mask.insert(END, "255.255.255.255")


def user_input_gateway():
    input_gateway = entry_gateway.get()
    display_gateway = input_gateway
    var_gateway.set(display_gateway)


entry_gateway = Entry(my_window, font="Helvetica 15", textvariable=var_gateway)
entry_gateway.place(x=35, y=230, width=158, height=30)
entry_gateway.bind("<Tab>", focus_next_widget)

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The methods for getting data out and inserting data into an entry widget are documented. Have you tried using them to accomplish your task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind `<KeyRelease>` event on the first entry and update second entry in the callback:

```
def on_entry_input(event):
    text = event.widget.get()
    # direct update second_entry
    second_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    second_entry.insert('end', text)
    # or via separate variable associated to second entry
    # second_entry_var.set(text)


first_entry = Entry(...)
first_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_entry_input)

second_entry = Entry(...)
```